# Regular expressions with validations in RoR 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There is the following code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
      with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
      message: 'URL must point to GIT/JPG/PNG pictures'
  }
end
```

It works, but when I try to test it using "rake test" I'll catch this message:

```
rake aborted!
The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i`? Maybe `%r{}` adds it's own `$` at the end.

Comment: @Wukerplank I don't think so. `%r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i #=> /\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i`, `%r{\.(gif|jpg|png)}i #=> /\.(gif|jpg|png)/i`.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help

Comment: @wukerplank why are we guessing? in ruby we have `irb` to help us know for sure :)

Comment: You need to remove the $ after png) which indicates that this is the last item and replace it with \z

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`^` and `$` are Start **of Line** and End **of Line** anchors. While `\A` and `\z` are Permanent Start **of String** and End **of String** anchors.
See the difference:

```
string = "abcde\nzzzz"
# => "abcde\nzzzz"

/^abcde$/ === string
# => true

/\Aabcde\z/ === string
# => false
```

So Rails is telling you, "Are you sure you want to use `^` and `$`? Don't you want to use `\A` and `\z` instead?"

There is more on the rails security concern that generates this warning [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions).

Comment: fixing up the unnecessary coloquialism

Comment: explains what it is asking but doesn't answer how to fix it. I suppose if you want to use ^ and $ the way to fix it is to add :multiline => true at the top of the class?

Comment: @isimmons By adding `:multiline => true` you only fix the warning saying Rails you know what you are doing.

Comment: The answer is there: it is to use \A and \z rather than ^ and $ because in Ruby, ^ and $ match only a newline not start and end of string, which allows a javascript exploit to pass the test.

Answer (score 31):

This warning raises because your validation rule is vulnerable for javascript injection.

In your case `\.(gif|jpg|png)$` matches till the end of the line. So your rule will validate this value `pic.png\nalert(1);` as true:

```
"test.png\n<script>alert(1)</script>" === /\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i
# => true

"test.png\n<script>alert(1)</script>" === /\.(gif|jpg|png)\z/i
# => false
```

Read the acticles:

- http://caiustheory.com/validating-data-with-regular-expressions-in-ruby
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions

Comment: Best of the bunch, wish we could make this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem regexp is not in devise, but rather lives in config/initializers/devise.rb.  Change:

```
# Regex to use to validate the email address
config.email_regexp = /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i
```

to:

```
# Regex to use to validate the email address
  config.email_regexp = /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\Z/i
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is telling you that strings like the following will pass validation, but it is probably not what you want:

```
test = "image.gif\nthis is not an image"
re = /\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i
re.match(test) #=> #<MatchData ".gif" 1:"gif">
```

Both `^` and `$` matches the start/end of any line, not the start/end of the string. `\A` and `\z` matches the start and the end of the full string, respectively.

```
re = /\.(gif|jpg|png)\z/i
re.match(test) #=> nil
```

The second part of the warning (“or forgot to add the :multiline => true option”) is telling you that if you actually want the behaviour of `^` and `$` you can simply silence the warning passing the `:multiline` option.

Comment: So where do you pass `:multiline`?

Answer (score -1):

If Ruby wants to see `\z` instead of the `$` symbol sign, for security, you need to give it to him, then the code would look like this :

```
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\z}i, message: 'URL must point to GIF, JPG, PNG.'}
```