# Rails validates with regex is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Simple regex is not working.. For example `first_name = "a11"` works fine. Why isn't my format regex validating properly?

```
  validates :first_name, presence: { message:  "Name cannot be blank." },
                         format: { with: /[a-z]/i, message:  "Name must only contain letters." },
                         length: { minimum: 2, message:  "Name must be at least 2 letters." }
```

Comment: What are trying to do?

Comment: See the regex? [a-z] only. But it doesn't validate. e.g. a329394 does not throw error.

Comment: @ff15 try `[0-9a]+` or `[0-9a-z]+`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it matches with you regex.

You have to specify the begin and end of the string, and add `*` or it will just match one char.

```
format: { with: /\A[a-z]*\z/i, message:  "Name must only contain letters." },
```

Also note don't use `^` and `$`, in ruby, `^` and `$` matches the begin and end of a **line**, not the string, so it will be broken on multiline strings.

Comment: Still not working... Palm to face! Wtf? How can I debug this? Any thoughts because this is just weird.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex returns a match. It's looking for any letter that's present anywhere in the string and returns that match. You want to specify that *only* letters are allowed.

**Update** Original answer insecure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17760113/836205

If you change it to <strike>`/^[a-z]*$/`</strike> `/\A[a-z]*\z/` it will only match a string that contains all lower case letters.

Comment: Your regex is invalid. It causes a security risk on rails. `The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?`

Comment: Ah, hadn't run into that before, thanks. It's valid but insecure. A good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17760113/836205