# Implementing minimum password complexity requirements in rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've built a User model and sign up along the lines of Michael Hartl's [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page). I have adapted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength) regex for minimum password complexity to check for

- at least one lower case letter
- at least one upper case letter
- at least one number
- at least one symbol

i.e.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$
```

The regex works perfectly as intended in [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Po8TyMWseQ), however, I have not been able to successfully implement it in my app

**What I've tried so far**

I've tried various combinations of

```
  VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$

  validates :password, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
```

With and without:

- double quotations around the regex e.g. "^(?=.* ... {8,}$"
- forward slashes around /VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX/
- the # in the [!@#$&*] part of the regex ('#' seems to be recognised as a comment in sublime text)

I keep getting errors along the lines of "A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :with" and "syntax error, unexpected '^'"

**What worked**

After reading assefamaru's answer, I was able to see the ^ and $ needed to be replaced with \A and \z (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759735/regular-expressions-with-validations-in-ror-4))

Here's what works:

```
  VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /\A(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$\z/
  validates :password, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in ruby's [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html), regexps are created using the `/.../` and `%r{...}` literals, and by the `Regexp::new` constructor. For example, you can have:

```
VALID_PASSWD = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$/
```

or

```
VALID_PASSWD = %r(^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$)
```

or

```
VALID_PASSWD = Regexp.new("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$")
```

Then, you can have the validation:

```
validates :password, format: { with: VALID_PASSWD }
```

---

Ps. In your [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Po8TyMWseQ) link, you might have noticed the forward slashes present to the left and right of the text-box containing the regex. This corresponds to the `/.../` literal for creating regexps.